# Does IE8 ignore Content-Type's charset in header?

Tags: unicode, internet-explorer-8, character-encoding

I have a very simple PHP file. I had set the charset using PHP's `header()` function as below...

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
```

Nothing was overwriting it, as I inspected the headers and it was coming through fine.

I am using a Unicode arrow (`→`) on my page. It is directly on the page, and not processed by any string manipulation functions.

It worked fine on Firefox and Safari, but in IE8 it came out as a mess (2 weird glyphs).

After some frustration, I added this to my `head` as well...

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

...and it fixed it.

What is the issue? Does IE8 ignore the charset in the header? Doesn't the `http-equiv` mean that it should be treated exactly like a normal header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your HTTP header contains `utf8`, but your meta tag contains `utf-8`. I'm fairly sure the latter is the correct name. Check if putting `utf-8` in the HTTP header helps.